# TFS Attach case to existing checkin

Tags: tfs, checkin

I checked in some code, but I forgot to attach the case. Is there a way I can go back and attach a case to an existing checkin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the "case" work item (I assume you're talking about a *test case* or *use case*)
- On the "All Links" tab click "Link to"
- Choose "Changeset" as Link type and select the appropriate changeset.
- Press OK

TFS links work in both directions, so by adding a link to the changeset in the work item, the changeset will also have a link to the work item.